# how to replace String s = "33 6.33"; to "336.33" in Java

Tags: java, string

it is a strange word; here my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "33 6.33";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*|\t|\r|\n");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    s = m.replaceAll("");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

but it doesn't work.

I found why the code did not work, the blank is non breaking space ....

Comment: Why not just `s = s.replaceAll("\\s*|\t|\r|\n","");` or yet better use the expression `\s*` (linebreaks and tabs are whitespace)?

Comment: `\s` covers `\t|\r|\n` already ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)): "A whitespace character: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`"

Comment: Match for 1 or more times, not 0 or more... `\\s+` instead of `\\s*`

Comment: @Codebender that shouldn't make a difference since 0-length matches would be replaced by 0-length strings anyways.

Comment: Btw, please specify "it doesn't work". Your code works for me...

Comment: @Thomas, that's right... It doesn't make a difference in his case...

Comment: eclipse  restart , my code works

Comment: The real question here is where did this data come from, and why was it presented to your application like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    s.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    //to remove multiple spaces even if you give more than 1 space it will do the job.
```

s - indicates space character.

Hope you  found the code helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression seems a little convoluted.  Why not just use String replace, thus:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "33 6.33";
    s = s.replace(" ", "");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "33 6.33";
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s+|\t|\r|\n","");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Try this, should fix your problem.

PS: You have wrong regex. Put '+' sign after s, not *.